# Deserialisation after serialisation does not work in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

Im trying to save and load some quite large Objects in C#. The Objects (all of the same type) are containing some Lists, some Dictionaries and a matrix of a native datatype. Of course it is filled with some values and it is, when serialized about 160Mb on the filesystem. The serialisation seems to work, but I have problems with the deserialisation. And I do not load them together, just simply one object per file and one per time.

I tried to use

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Matrix, Formatting.Intended);
 File.WriteAllText(FilePath, json);
```

for loading i tried

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(FilePath);
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
matrix = (MatrixStructure) serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(MatrixStructure));
```

as well as

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
MatrixStructure matrix = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MatrixStructure>(json);
```

Both cases did not work for me. In both cases I get the same Exception:

> > Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyObject1]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

I assumed that the deserialisation should work, because it is the same class I serialized. But there seems to be a problem with an internal list

Is there maybe a limitation for the size of the json files that can be loaded (I'm trying to load 160Mb and it could be that later i get even bigger files) and therefore something is missing?

Or do I have to use a other function to serialize and deserialize the json? Maybe write it propertywise?

Comment: Where's the Json string?

Comment: Please verify again that `Matrix` is of type `MatrixStructure`.

Comment: What is the type of the Matrix variable?

Comment: I will recommend [mcve]. We do not need the 160Mb Json. In fact we don't even need the real data. Just the minimal json to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You serialised using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(**Matrix**, Formatting.Intended); , and deserialise to DeserializeObject<**MatrixStructure**>. And then say _"because it is the same class I serialized"_. It look like a typo.

Comment: The Json string is the autogenerated string from the class. It is just saved with the serializeObject function and without changing it is loaded again without changing, therefore i thought that there should be no error in it (and due to all public variables inside the class it should get all values).

The type is correct i checked it multiple times.

The matrix and matrixstructure are the same, i will clearify it in the code

Comment: Not quite sure without seeing your JSON string but you can try deserializing your string into `dynamic`: `var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry for your time, i figured it out while trying to make the minimal example.

There was one getter from a formal private variable left it had the form

```
public Dictionary<int, obj> GetDict => _dict
```

and I assume that there was a cast that didn't work.
It could be seen in the Json from the attribute that was written as GetDict instead of _dict. Due to the fact, that it was originally a pure getter the converter could not find the setter and it could not work.